# javascript alert stopping the rest of page from rendering in php

Tags: php

I am displaying success msg after inserting records in database in javascript alert like this:

`echo '<script type="text/javascript"> 
         $(document).ready(function() {
                 alert("Record inserted");
         });
      </script>';`

It displays alert message after half page load and then after clicking ok in alert, rest of the page is rendering.
How can I display alert message after full page load?

Comment: use window load, instead dom ready: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: Sidenote: php has nothing to do with this, when the alert is fired (when the html is served to the client, actually) php has already rendered the page. The problem is the browser is waiting for the alert to continue processing

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(window).load()`.

```
$(window).load(function() { /* ... */ });
```